# running spring mvc application using intelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

i've cloned a repository and trying to run a spring mvc application in intelliJ. I've noticed that I'm missing some .jar files in my project library for maven. Just wondering what the easiest way to correct this. Fresh maven install?

[image: missing source .jar files]

thanks

Comment: ... No, set IntelliJ to download the source and javadoc jars as well as the classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors appear because you don't have the sources and javadoc downloaded. Go to **Maven Projects > Download Sources and Documentation**.

**NOTE** some sources are not provided so some errors will persist

[image]

Comment: View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Projects